# PHP UTF-8 Encoding is messing up

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8, multilingual

I'm outputting some multi-lingual data from my database into a JSON object, but the output isn't showing foreign characters, it just shows question marks even though I have the header charset set to utf8 as such:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

When I look at the data in phpMyAdmin, it shows the characters correctly. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here is the PHP code that is formatting the JSON output:

```
$numRows = new stdClass();

$mysqli = dbiConnect();
$query = "SELECT * FROM country_codes";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* store result */
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numRows->cc = $stmt->num_rows;

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();

$count = 0;
$dataCountryCodes = '{';
    $mysqli = dbiConnect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM country_codes";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $count++;
            $rowData = new stdClass();
            $rowData->code = $row['code'];
            $rowData->name = $row['name'];
            $dataCountryCodes = $dataCountryCodes.'"'.$rowData->code.'": {"Code":"'.$rowData->code.'","Country":"'.$rowData->name.'"}';

            if ($count != $numRows->cc) {
                $dataCountryCodes = $dataCountryCodes.',';
            }
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
$dataCountryCodes = $dataCountryCodes.'}';
if ($returnCountryCodes == 1) {
    return $dataCountryCodes;
} else {

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo ($dataCountryCodes);
}
```

This is what I am getting:

```
{"AE": {"Code":"AE","Country":"United Arab Emirates (???????? ???????? ????????)"}}
```

This is what I got when it was hand coded, this would render fine after I translated the JSON to HTML:

```
{"AE": {"Code":"AE","Country":"United Arab Emirates (Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ù…Ø§Ø±Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠÙ‘Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù…ØªÙ‘Ø­Ø¯Ø©)"}}
```

Comment: Are you sure the data's coming out of the database correct, or was properly put into the database in the first place? Your DB tables/fields might be set for utf-8, but your **ENTIRE** rendering pipeline has to be set for utf-8 as well, including the php<->db connection. phpmyadmin is probably showing it right because it has a properly configured connection, whereas your code isn't

Comment: @MarcB I added more detail, the data in the DB is fine when I view it in the DB admin tool...

Comment: What's inside `dbiConnect()`? I'm guessing that your database connection character set is not defined properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show dbiConnect function. Check it and try using `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` after connecting to MySQL:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pw", "db");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Failed to connect to mySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_errno());
}

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $con->error);
}
```

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) says:

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server... It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$mysqli = dbiConnect();
$mysqli->query("set names utf8")
```